# Why my bot.py code using selenoid isn't running on ubuntu server when I close my ssh bash window?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu-server, selenoid

I have set up on local machine an ubuntu server on which I run bot.py code using ssh bash terminal. My bot.py get's url  from my contacts  and visits webpages using docker and selenoid. I have set up docker and selenoid and they work well. When I run:

```
$ sudo ./myscript_ro_run_bot.sh
```

[inside myscript_ro_run_bot.sh]:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  echo "running bot.py"
  nohup sudo python3 bot.py # nohup to run at background
  wait
  echo "bot.py finished"
  echo "running bot1.py"
  nohup sudo python3 bot1.py
  wait
  echo "bot1.py finished"
  .....
  echo "runnning bot5.py"
  nohup sudo python3 bot5.py
  sleep 10m
done
```

(I have 5 bot.py files)

I can see on local machine messages in Telegram that (myscript_ro_run_bot.sh) doing it's job well that sites have been visited and I get rewarded. Even on local machine the (myscript_ro_run_bot.sh) can be ran 24/7 hours (indefinitely). But I want to run on server 24/7 hours. The problem is when I close ssh bash window manager I see on local machine Telegram that nothing happening, I don't get messages. Here is the trick when I connect to my server with ssh again after 5 or an hour and only after reconnection I start receiving messages in telegram. I can see job running in server with command:
`$ htop`
that my command `sudo python3 bot.py` is running
When I used:

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

`@reboot /home/user/myscript_ro_run_bot.sh >> /home/user/myscrit_to_run_bot.log`

After reboot I connected to server with ssh and got result from myscrit_to_run_bot.log:

```
running bot.py
bot.py finished
running bot1.py
bot1.py finished
running bot3.py
```

But I didn't get any messages in telegram after reconnection.
Whereas I run my script manually and reconnect to server I get messages in telegram.

Can anybody help me how to solve the issue? I want `sudo ./myscript_ro_run_bot.sh` to run even I close ssh bash terminal.
If you want me to provide more details please write `commands` as well (detail instruction) because I am new on coding and linux.
I appreciate your help

Comment: Does not seem to be related to Selenoid, so Selenoid team is ignoring this question.

Comment: @vania-pooh I checked the python3 script (appended text with datetime, so I could see if I am out connection whether the script will write or not). I disconnected the ssh and reconnected back in 5 minutes, and saw the  the script worked while I was disconnected. So I guess the problem with selenoid. How can I check that selenoid is working well while I am connected and disconnected ssh? Where can Isee the logs

Comment: You should be able to execute everything remotely just by replacing `localhost` with VM host name or IP address instead. There is no need to use sophisticated and strange SSH-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `screen` or `tmux` for launching your process https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Tmux

1. run `tmux`
2. run `./your_program`
3. enter `ctrl+b` and then `d`

After this, your process will be run in the background, and you can close ssh-connection.
When you need back, you can run `tmux attach`